# Can you convert a Timestamp to a FieldValue?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

In my app, user will upload a document to the database under their subcollection, with a Timestamp attached to the document. In my Security Rules, I have it programmed so that the Timestamp will always be equal to `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. This saves a FieldValue to the database.

The problem is, whenever I get the documentSnapshot back from Firebase and access the field, it comes back as a Timestamp and not a FieldValue. Is there a way I can convert a Timestamp to a FieldValue, or vice-versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you really do want that Timestamp instead of a FieldValue.  [FieldValue](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue) tokens are only used for writing field values that need to have their actual values computed on the Firestore backend instead of on the client.  They are just tokens, not actual values.  When you fetch the document and read the value back out, it will have the actual Timestamp value (or whatever the final value is), which is what you need to work with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I do have one question though. I was updating a class in my project, replacing FieldValue with Timestamp, and I had to update how the document was uploaded as a result. When I used FieldValues, `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` was uploaded to the database. Now with Timestamps, I upload `Timestamp.now()` instead. Are these the same values, or is one slightly different?

Comment: Alas, you misunderstand Doug's response... FieldValue.serverTimestamp() is NOT a value at ALL; it is a FLAG to the server to generate a timestamp (using Firestore's format) and write it into the indicated field.

something like Timestamp.now() *is* a value - you might use it as field value in a query, for example.

Comment: `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is computed on the Firestore backend using its own clock.  `Timestamp.now()` is computed on the client using is own clock.  As I said, FieldValue tokens do not have values on the client.  They are just tokens sent to the backend for it to evaluate the final value.